# Problems with invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want that when the staff is logged in to their page and is going to press 'completed' on their work shifts, it should be marked as completed for both the staff and the customer. However, it's not working at the moment; I just receive error messages about invalid documents. The code I'm sending here is from the staff page where the staff's work shifts are displayed

so this is the function that should do the work but it doesnt work..

```
  const handleDoneBooking = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      const batch = writeBatch(db);
      const adminBookingRef = doc(db, "users", emailAdmin, "booking", id);
      const customerBookingRef = doc(db, "users", emailLogin, "booking", id);
      batch.update(adminBookingRef, { status: true });
      batch.update(customerBookingRef, { status: true });

      await batch.commit();

      setCleaner((prev) =>
        prev.map((book) => (book.id === id ? { ...book, status: true } : book))
      );

     
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating booking:", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: One of these variables doesn't have a value: `emailAdmin`, `emailLogin` or `id`. Log their values to find out which one.

Comment: when i console.log(id) console.log(emailAdmin) console.log(emailLogin) i get it in the console and when i console.log(customerBookingRef) i get everything and also if I comment out this  const customerBookingRef = doc(db, "users", emailLogin, "booking", id); and this batch.update(customerBookingRef, { status: true }); it works

Comment: Are you sure the error message comes from the code you shared then? What specific line throws the error?